# Using .animate and .css or just one in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
var help;
    $('.helpPin').click(function(){

        if(help == true){
            var cssObj = {
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'bottom' : '0'
            };
            $('#help').css(cssObj);
            help = false;
        } else {
            var cssObj = {
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'bottom' : '-206px'
            };
            $('#help').css(cssObj);
            help = true;
        }
    });
```

That basically just swaps css for an element, how can i introduce animate effects to so its not too jerky? Can you use .css inside .animate?

Comment: [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) would be better.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. For an animated version, use [jQuery UI `toggleClass`](http://jqueryui.com/docs/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, addinga/amending CSS properties directly in jQuery is considered bad practice. All you need to do is set the position on the element in your CSS:

CSS

```css
#help {
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can then refactor your jQuery code to cut it down drastically, and also animate your element as required:

```
var help;

$('.helpPin').click(function(){
    var bottom = help ? '0' : '-206px';
    $("#help").animate({ 'bottom' : bottom });
    help = !help;
});
```

Comment: Short, intelligent, efficient. *hat tip*

Comment: help = !help; can you expand on this slightly please? Does it set a variable to the opposite of its current value?

Comment: @benhowdle89 that's correct - it will invert a boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

A [***working demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/Jx4Md/)

```
#help
{
    position: absolute;
}

$('.helpPin').click(function(){
        if(help == true){
            $('#help').animate({"bottom": '0'});
            help = false;
        } else {
            $('#help').animate({"bottom": '-206px'});
            help = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to code less and more efficient way.

```
var help;
    $('.helpPin').click(function(){

        if(help == true){               
            $('#help').css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'bottom' : '0'
            }).animate();
            help = false;
        } else {
            $('#help').css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'bottom' : '-206px'
            }).animate();
            help = true;
        }
    });
```

Hope, you'are looking for the same.

Comment: I had given you the logic that about how to start up. What sort of animation you want? You want me to give the exact code? Your code exist on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the position using CSS, in the meantime......

```
var help;
$('.helpPin').click(function () {

     var bottom = (help) ? '0' : '-206px';

     $('#help')
          .css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
          .animate({ 'bottom': bottom });

     help = !help;
});
```